# How to read and write tfrecord files of 2d array

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I want to make a 2d array of size (n, 3) to a `tfrecord file`, and read it.

The code I wrote to make `tfrecord file` is

```py
def _float_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value))
```

```py
example = tf.train.Example(
      features=tf.train.Features(
          feature={
              'arry_x':_float_feature(array[:,0]),
              'arry_y':_float_feature(array[:,1]),
              'arry_z':_float_feature(array[:,2])}
         )
      )

with tf.compat.v1.python_io.TFRecordWriter(file_name) as writer:
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

And I tried to read the file with `TFRecordReader`

```py
def get_tfrecord_feature():
    return{
        'arry_x': tf.compat.v1.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
        'arry_y': tf.compat.v1.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
        'arry_z': tf.compat.v1.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32)
    }
```

```py
filenames = [file_name, file_name2, ...]
file_name_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(file_name_queue)

data = tf.compat.v1.io.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=get_tfrecord_feature())

x = data['arry_x']
y = data['arry_y']
z = data['arry_z']

x, y, z = tf.train.batch([x, y, z], batch_size=1)
```

And I used the tf.Session to check the code

```py
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(x))
```

The code runs with no error, but the session doesn't print any value.
I think the way to read the `tfrecord file` was wrong.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add the list length which in your case is **array.shape[0]** as below to the features definition when parse the tf record.

```
def get_tfrecord_feature():
    return{
        'arry_x': tf.compat.v1.io.FixedLenFeature([array.shape[0]], tf.float32),
        'arry_y': tf.compat.v1.io.FixedLenFeature([array.shape[0]], tf.float32),
        'arry_z': tf.compat.v1.io.FixedLenFeature([array.shape[0]], tf.float32)
    }
```

You can leave the shape as [] if there is only one element for FixedLenFeature.
https://tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/io/FixedLenFeature

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for donglinjy's advice, I fixed my code here

```py
def get_tfrecord_feature():
    return{
        'arry_x': tf.compat.v1.io.FixedLenFeature([array.shape[0]], tf.float32),
        'arry_y': tf.compat.v1.io.FixedLenFeature([array.shape[0]], tf.float32),
        'arry_z': tf.compat.v1.io.FixedLenFeature([array.shape[0]], tf.float32)
    }
```

and here.

```py
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    coord=tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads=tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    print(sess.run(x))
```

It works now.